# How do I make a very, VERY specific horizontal line?

Tags: margins, rules

I am having a lot of trouble while formatting my resume.  Everything is done except for one last feather in my cap: I want to have a horizontal line (below the name title) that starts at the left side of the page to the right side margin.  I have tried a variety of options, including

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

\begin{center}
\noindent \line(1,0){350}
\end{center}

\rule{14.5cm}{.1mm}

\hrulefill
```

Nothing has worked so far, with the lines either only going from margin to margin, or going from the left side of the pagewidth to the actual right side of the page.  Any advice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Welcome. You might want to add the documentclass, or better make the code snippet compilable.

Answer (score 2):

The left margin is 1inch plus `\oddsidemargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent\hspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin}%
\rule{\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth}{2pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]